# IE11 css live editor cutoff css text inappropriately

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

When I enter "break-all;" in css editor, it end up with this:

[image: ie10 bug]

I also tried to paste into the editor and get the same result.

Any ideas?

### Update

Sorry, It's IE11 vesion:11.0.9600.16518, KB2909921, not IE10.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Notice the difference between `break-all` and `break-al`

Comment: I did entered `word-break: break-all;` but IE cut the last 'l' off

Comment: Works fine for me on IE10, what editor are you using?

Comment: my bad. It's IE11. not 10.